# How to delete multiple list items in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make an MVC4 application with EF database first, which i just started learning 2 days ago by myself. 
The problem i am facing is that i have a list of customers, which has an attribute "IsDeleted" with value true or false.

Basically I want to delete all of the customers which has their attribute IsDeleted marked as true at the same time by clicking a link or button.

So far I have tried to do these, but it seems I am still a bit blurry about how it all works:

In my CustomerController i added these codes:

```
        public ActionResult DeleteAll()
    {
        List<Customer> cusList = new List<Customer>();
        IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = db.Customers.ToList().Where(i => i.IsDeleted == true);
        foreach (var Item in customerList) { cusList.Add(Item); }
        return View(customerList);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteAll")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteAllConfirmed()
    {
        List<Customer> cusList = new List<Customer>();
        IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = db.Customers.ToList().Where(i => i.IsDeleted == true);
        foreach (var Item in customerList) { cusList.Add(Item); }
        foreach (var item in cusList) { db.Customers.Remove(item); }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

So i am a bit unsure where to go next or even if this is viable as an approach.
If it is viable, how to invoke this action in views?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some redundant code in your post method. You are querying the database and get the result you want. This entities in turn are thrown into a list and after this you are iterating over them to delete them. In addition you are forgetting to tell your context to save the changes. You can scrape off some time, memory and cpu cycles by shortening this:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteAll")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteAllConfirmed()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = db.Customers.Where(i => i.IsDeleted == true);
    //Now you have everything you need.
    foreach (var Item in customerList) 
    { 
        //Remove
        db.Customers.Remove(Item); 
    }
    //and save. done
    db.SaveChanges(); //important!
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Your `DeleteAll()` method has also some flaws. You are adding items to your `cusList` but you never use it!

```
public ActionResult DeleteAll()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = db.Customers.Where(i => i.IsDeleted == true);
    return View(customerList);
}
```

If you wanted to, you could reduce this to one line:

```
public ActionResult DeleteAll()
{
    return View(db.Customers.Where(i => i.IsDeleted == true));
}
```

I am yet a bit unsure, of what you mean by how to invoke this in views.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a fast reply, when i asked how to invoke it, i mean i want to have a view to list all those items which are marked true to be deleted, then I would have a button or an actionlink in that view to click and it will be all deleted. I hope it is clearer?

Comment: This is pretty basic. Right click on your `DeleteAll()` method and then on generate view. Select a list template. In this view you can create a button which calls the `DeleteAllConfirmed()` POST method and you are done. I suggest you work through the offical tutorials at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: I have managed to do it, It was a typo before which made me think my code is wrong, thank you again for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer did help you, think about upvoting it, or mark it as the answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried to upvote but i need 15 reputation to do so. I marked it as answer though!